# How to get a path where the cocoa program runs?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, shell

In main function body, I need to call system(RELATIVE_PATH + /MyShellScript.sh). The script and other related stuff resides in main project bundle. How to get relative path? IMHO it should be possible to extract it from main parameter - "char *argv[]"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSLog(@"%s", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
2012-01-24 21:33:22.015 CLIXMPLParser[13042:707] /Users/zrxq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CLIXMPLParser-dsibnvwgoqvjnvbhlxkyzcojqnwr/Build/Products/Debug/CLIXMPLParser
```

Comment: While `argv[0]` *may* contain the path to your application I don't believe there is any guarantee that it will - in the underlying API the path and `argv[0]` are distinct parameters and can be different (this feature is actually used by certain programs to determine their behaviour - the test `argv[0]` for different values). The correct answer for Cocoa is to use `NSBundle` as in Rob Keniger's answer.

Comment: @CRD is right; `argv[0]` contains the name by which the executable was invoked, which is not necessarily the same as the full path to it.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly are you trying to do? What is your shell script doing, and why are you calling it from `main()`? You should not normally need to modify the `main()` function in a Cocoa app.

Generally, you should avoid using a shell script unless absolutely necessary, but if you must then you should create an `NSTask` object and use that to execute your script. If you want to run it at launch, you should place your code to launch your script in the application delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method.

You can get the path to resources inside your app's bundle using the various methods of `NSBundle`:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyShellScript" ofType:@"sh"];
```

Comment: You see, I have downloaded Oracle JDeveloper tool (a folder that contains inner folders and java files in it) however, the tools runs though some shell script in some 2nd level folder. So, I was curious how to make a "wrapper" around that jdeveloper, just wanted to create .app package, for convenience. Currently, I'm able to ran the script and jdeveloper from a predefined location, so needed to know how to pass a relative path to system() call.